# Cocoa - get current window position on screen

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

How can I retrieve the current NSWindow's position on main screen?

I've been searching and trying for a while and still nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSWindow has a [`frame`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSWindow/frame) property which is a rectangle (NSRect) representing its position/size on the screen.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I used it but it displayed the same location all the time. I needed to set up a delegate, as I displayed view of customViewController in another window (main window of AppDelegate), and what I was doing all the time was retrieving the position of window from customViewController, which was not changing obviously. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to watch for changes, you can use the delegate method `windowDidMove:` or listen for the notification `NSWindowDidMoveNotification`.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to use that one as well! It didn't fit my needs and now I'm trying to figure out how to get current window position while dragging this window. I'm trying to use .addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask with .LeftMouseDraggedMask but it only return the position of dragging window after I stop for a while (not live).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you just want another window to track the position of this window, you might try using `addChildWindow:`.